# Download images and resize

Tags: php, iphone

I have built a system which downloads images from a bunch of URLs, depending on the user, and fetch's them asynchronously - if they're wider than the device's screen we resize. Trouble is some of these images can be huge 1MB + and many of them and downloading large files and processing them is causing the older devices to struggle.

So I thought I'd introduce a server side level which can handle the downloading and resizing...but my PHP is not great. I'm guessing this is possible but I cant find any solutions after a few days research. There are an abundance of PHP resize scripts, but none from a URL, they are all from a database or inside HTML . I need it to be sent a URL of an image, download it, if its too big resize, then send back to the device.

---

Updated with cURL

```
<?php

$imgurl = $_GET["url"];

function curl_download($Url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($output);

    if ($im !== false)
    {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($im);
        $new_width = 320;
        $new_height = 320;

        // Resample
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($im);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'An error occurred.';
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $image_p;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the image with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with `CURLOPT_RETURN_TRANSFER` passed to `curl_setopt` to get the image data. Then the following steps should do for generating the resized image:

1. [`imagecreatefromstring`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring)
   will allow you to construct an image object
2. [`imagecreate`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate)
   to create a new image of the appropriate size
3. [`imagecopyresampled`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled)
   for the resize
4. [`imagejpeg`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg) on the resized image to send it to the browser

As @Paul notes, you'll want to set the content type to `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Thanks, thing is I dont want to send it to a browser in that way, I need the Data that the cURL originally receives. Is there a way to turn the imagejpeg back into that data form?

Comment: Don't convert it to an image object in the first place. If you set `CURLOPT_RETURN_TRANSFER`, then `curl_exec` will return the data.

Comment: I have updated my question with the cURL code im using. How do I get it to return the new image in a data form, like the output I originally got from `$output = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: You can call `ob_start()`, `imagejpeg` to output the image, then `ob_get_clean()` to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cURL or socket to download the html page and images in it, then use GD2 to resize the images, and return to browser with

```
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
```

after that, your application on iphone load this php created image from your php server. i think this is the solution for manipulating all the images from other servers the way you want.